# Track google analytics on Android Studio webview

Tags: android, ios, webview, google-analytics

My app has a webview which is displaying a webpage from a partner company which we are working with. They have asked if there is a way for them to see on there Google Analytics when a user has viewed the webview/webpage on our app. Is this possible to let there google analytics account know when the page view is coming from our mobile apps webview?

Comment: did you open webview in activity ?

Comment: exactly, the webview is opened on activity start

Comment: ok than you can use google analytics, initialize in `onCreate()`  after that its views count will be automatically handled by analytics.

Comment: ok, I will do that. Thanks for the quick response!